# Dict.setdefault insert sorted into a list

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I'm wondering if there is a way of using a lambda like style to append to a dictionarie's list field sorted.

**Example:**

```
a = {}
a.setdefault("foo", []).append(2)
a.setdefault("foo", []).append(1)
{'foo': [2, 1]}
```

Is there a way of doing an `insert in sorted order` as using `a["foo"].bisect.insort(a, -1)`, so that I don't need to call sort afterwards?

Comment: "Insertion sort" does not mean "sort when inserting" or "insert an element at the point that preserves sorted order"; it is a specific sorting algorithm.

Comment: That's right, i was too ambiguous with my . I'll correct this.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is in Pythons standard library:

```
import bisect
from collections import defaultdict


def add(dd, key, value):
    bisect.insort_left(dd[key], value)


a = defaultdict(list)
add(a, "foo", 3)
add(a, "foo", 2)
add(a, "foo", 1)
add(a, "foo", 3)
add(a, "foo", 2)
add(a, "foo", 1)

assert a["foo"] == sorted(a["foo"])
print(a)
```

if you want a lambda:

```
add = lambda dd, key, value: bisect.insort_left(dd[key], value)
```

In terms of performance using `sort` afterwards runtime should be faster than  using `bisect.insort_left`. In both cases runtime complexity is *O(n log n)* but function call overhead should result in different absolute run times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections.defaultdict` instead, with some `SortedList` implementation (downloaded with `pip install sortedcontainers`, but there are others):

```
import collections
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

a = collections.defaultdict(SortedList)
a["foo"].add(2)
a["foo"].add(1)
print(a)
```

result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'sortedcontainers.sortedlist.SortedList'>, {'foo': SortedList([1, 2])})
```

you could override `add` by `append` if you have a lot of code to refactor.

note that it also works with `setdefault`, but more cumbersome:

```
a = {}
a.setdefault("foo", SortedList()).add(2)
a.setdefault("foo", SortedList()).add(1)
```

(and doing that on a lot of elements has the disadvantage of creating a `SortedList()` object just in case the key doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this, with a helper function:

```
def list_append(lst, item):
    lst.append(item)
    return lst

a = {}
list_append(a.setdefault("foo", []), 2).sort()
list_append(a.setdefault("foo", []), 1).sort()
```

But I will definitely recommend you try other data structure, like `heapq`.